# SwiftUI - disable certain views from flipping for right to left languages

Tags: ios, swiftui, localization, arabic, right-to-left

When our app runs in a right to left language like Hebrew or Arabic, the SwiftUI views automatically flip the positions of our views to be right to left. Some of this is very helpful, but certain views should not be flipped.

We tried [.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(false)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/flipsforrighttoleftlayoutdirection(_:)) on the views but this didn't prevent them from being positioned differently when running with the scheme set to Hebrew or Arabic.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `.environment(\.layoutDirection, .leftToRight)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the layout direction using `.environment`:

```
.environment(\.layoutDirection, .leftToRight)
```

Comment: Edge screen Swipe back action not working from right to left, it's still is left to right but presenting animation is right to left.